# Finding the condition number of an iterative method.

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson

I'm trying to find the condition number on the function $A$ for the iterative method below however I'm struggling to begin.

$$p_{n+1}=p_n-A(p_n)\frac{f(p_n)}{f'(p_n)}=g(p_n)$$

**In particular, the problem is:** Given $f(x)$ has a simple root at $x=p$ and $f$ is sufficiently differentiable, derive a condition on function $A$ which will ensure convergence from a sufficiently accurate $p_0$.

---

I know that the relative condition number is defined as

$$K(d) = \frac {\|\delta x\| /\|x\|}{\|\delta d\|/\|d\|}=\|G'(d)\| \frac{\|d\|}{\|G(d)\|}$$

or the ratio of the perturbations in $x$ relative to the perturbations in data $d$. Also, $x:=G(d)$. But how do I begin to apply this definition the the iterative method above. Is it simply $p_{n+1}=G(A)$?

Some indication on how to begin would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question is not about the *condition number*, but about a *condition on the function* $A(p)$. You need to apply the fixed point theorem to the mapping $p \mapsto g(p) = p - A(p) \frac{f(p)}{f'(p)}$. For sufficiently accurate initial guess a sufficient condition would be $|g'(p)| \leq q < 1$.

Comment: I totally misinterpreted the question. Thanks!